# Setting the date position to the top right in a NF.lco (french style) scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I want to place the date above the receiver address with KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2`.  I'm using the `NF.lco` or `\LoadLetterOption{NF}`

In French letters,

- the first line contains the date, flushed to the right
- then the sender address on the left
- then the receiver address on the right
- then the subject
- ...

I can use the excellent [`lettre` class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettre) from 'Observatoire de Genève' to obtain the correct french layout (see below), but I'm constrained by [my org-mode export](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html) tool using `scrlttr2` as the LaTeX class.

How do I do that ?

In fact I'de love to have an org-mode tool to export directly to the `lettre` class.  An alternative would be to reproduce the 'lettre' layout in a `.lco` file. but that not my question here.

I probably have not read enough linearly [the official documentation](https://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) but random regex search in it for 'date' 'date.*position' 'position' did not give me satisfying results.

Below are illustration of what I have and then what I want

**What I have**

[image]

for the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,french]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}

\setlength\parskip{\medskipamount} \setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{lipsum} \setstretch{1.15}

\LoadLetterOption{NF}%                         

\KOMAoptions{%
   fromalign=left% alignment of the address
  ,fromphone=true%         print sender phone number 
  ,fromemail=true%  print sender e-mail address  
  ,fromlogo=true%         print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
}

\setkomavar{date}{le \today}

\setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small} 
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape} 
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ } 
\setkomavar{backaddress}{}

\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~:~} \setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > } \setkomavar{fromaddress}{7-13 rue dejourney\\  49000 ANGERS} \setkomavar{fromemail}{gigiair@gigiair.fr} \setkomavar{fromname}{Gigiair} \setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 456 789} \setkomavar{phoneseparator}{~:~} \setkomavar{place}{Angers} \setkomavar{signature}{\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \quad  \quad \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{signature}} \setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> } \setkomavar{subject}{Modèle}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}


\begin{letter}{\`A Madame la centurion\\
    Camps de Babaurum\\
    Bretagne conquise}   \def\concname{Objet :~} 

  \opening{Madame la centurion,}   C'est une invitation pour manger du sanglier roti.   \closing{à la tienne !}

  \cc{Panoramix et Obleix} \end{letter} \end{document}
```

**and what I want**

[image]

from the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt, francais]{lettre} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[francais]{babel} \usepackage{mathcomp} \usepackage{url}

\makeatletter \newcommand*{\NoRule}{\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}} \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}   {\`A Madame la centurion
    \\Camps de Babaurum
    \\Bretagne conquise}   \def\concname{Objet :~}    \conc{Fête au village}

  \NoRule

  \name{Abraracourcix chef}   \address{Village des irréductibles Gaulois\\ Armorique}   \lieu{Bretagne Libre}

  \telephone{0123 456 789}   \nofax   \email{goscini@uderzo.be}

  \opening{Madame la centurion,}   C'est une invitation pour manger du sanglier roti.   \closing{à la tienne !}

  \cc{Panoramix et Obleix}


\end{letter} \end{document}
```

Adding a page from scrguien.pdf (KOMA-Script manual) that could help other readers coming here

[image]

Comment: Attention: Do not just look at the pseudo-length image from the documentation, but read the descriptions of the pseudo-lengths carefully. Some of them are set to special values by default, eg. `0pt`. Then the class calculates the length of the positions of the letter elements when "opening". The rules for the calculations are described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I do not know the rules for french letters (is'nt there a `*.lco` file for french speaking swiss, simular to letters in france?) I let it to you to work it out precisley.

In your case you need to define a new `firsthead` like:

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \normalsize
  Angers, le \today % <=================================================
}
```

Please see I added the place and date directly in the code above (marking `<======`). 
To get no place and date printed in the refline you need to use the following two lines:

```
%\setkomavar{place}{Angers} 
\date{}
```

Please see the following complete code

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=11pt,
  french,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{verbose,a4paper,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}

\setlength\parskip{\medskipamount} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\setstretch{1.15}
\LoadLetterOption{NF}%

\KOMAoptions{% 
   fromalign=left% alignment of the address
  ,fromphone=true% print sender phone number
  ,fromemail=true% print sender e-mail address
  ,fromlogo=true% print a logo (position depends on fromalign) 
}

%\setkomavar{date}{le \today}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small} 
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape} 
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ } 
\setkomavar{backaddress}{}

\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~:~} 
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > } 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{7-13 rue dejourney\ 49000 ANGERS} 
\setkomavar{fromemail}{gigiair@gigiair.fr} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{Gigiair} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 456 789} 
\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{~:~} 
%\setkomavar{place}{Angers} % <=========================================
\date{} % <============================================================
\setkomavar{signature}{\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \quad \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}} 
\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> } 
\setkomavar{subject}{Modèle}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{% <==============================================
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \normalsize
  Angers, le \today % <=================================================
}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize} % <========================================
\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot} % <=====================


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{`A Madame la centurion\ Camps de Babaurum\ Bretagne conquise} 
\def\concname{Objet :~}
\opening{Madame la centurion,} 
C'est une invitation pour manger du sanglier roti. 
\closing{à la tienne !}
\cc{Panoramix et Obleix} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result]

Please see that the call of `\LoadLetterOption{visualize}` activates the tool of `scrarttl2` to visualize special fields, named in `\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot}`.

If that is a real standard format for french letters, please contact the maintainer of KOMA-Script at https://komascript.de/  (you can write in english) and ask for a feature request to realize this french letter format via pur lco file ...

Comment: Another thing.  I like your answer but I find strange the way you place the signature with \quad .... What If I want the signature aligned with the receiver adresse ?  I need a way to find my way in the koma official doc.

Comment: @MalikKoné well, I simply took your used signature with `\quad`.  You can change the used indent for the signatur for example with `\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{refhpos}}`. The negative value of `toaddrhpos` means that it counts from the right pager side, not the left as shown in the picture in documentation ...

Answer (score 2):

With the suggestion below you can still use `\setkomavar{date}{...}` and `\setkomavar{place}{...}` and you can enable/disable the usage of `fromphone` and `fromemail` using options `fromphone` and `fromemail`, respectivly. If variable `place` is empty, the place seperator will be removed.

Note, that the contents of variable `firsthead` overwrittes both option `fromalign` and `fromlogo`. To remove the back address you can set option `backaddress=false`. Do not change `\parskip` manually, use option `parskip` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,french]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed with an uptodate TeX Distribution
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}

\KOMAoptions{parskip=half-}%<- do not set \parskip manually

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{url}% <- added

\LoadLetterOption{NF}%

\KOMAoptions{%
  %fromalign=center% <- no effect because of \setkomavar{firsthead}{...}
  ,fromphone=true
  ,fromemail=true
  %,fromlogo=true% <- no effect because of \setkomavar{firsthead}{...}
  ,backaddress=false% <- remove backaddress
  ,refline=nodate% <- remove date from the refline
  ,subject=titled% <- use a title for the subject
}

\renewcaptionname{french}{\subjectname}{Objet}% like your lettre version
\addtokomafont{subject}{\normalfont}% <- like your lettre version

\renewcaptionname{french}{\ccname}{C.c.}% like your lettre version
\setkomavar{ccseparator}{}
\setkomavar*{ccseparator}{\llap{\ccname\quad}}% like your lettre version

\setkomavar{placeseparator}{, le }

\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}

\setkomavar{emailseparator}[E-Mail]{~:~}% <- like your lettre version
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{7-13 rue dejourney\\  49000 ANGERS}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\url{gigiair@gigiair.fr}}% <- like your lettre version
\setkomavar{fromname}{Gigiair}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 456 789}
\setkomavar{phoneseparator}[Tél]{.~}% <- like your lettre version
\setkomavar{place}{Angers}
\setkomavar{signature}{\hspace{26em}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}}% <- changed
\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{~:~}% <- like your lettre version
\setkomavar{subject}{Modèle}

\makeatletter
\setkomavar{firsthead}{{%
  \usekomafont{fromaddress}%
  \parbox[b]{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
    {\usekomafont{fromname}\usekomavar{fromname}}
    \hfill{\usekomafont{placeanddate}%
      \ifkomavarempty{place}{}{\usekomavar{place}\usekomavar{placeseparator}}%
      \usekomavar{date}%
    }%
    \\\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
    \medskip% similar to the lettre version
    \if@phone\\\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\fi
    \if@mobilephone\\\usekomavar*{frommobilephone}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\fi%
    \if@fax\\\usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\fi
    \if@email\\\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\fi
    \if@www\\\usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}\fi
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\`A Madame la centurion\\
    Camps de Babaurum\\
    Bretagne conquise}
\def\concname{Objet :~} 

  \opening{Madame la centurion,}
  C'est une invitation pour manger du sanglier roti.
  \closing{à la tienne !}

  \cc{Panoramix et Obleix}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you esdd, but how do you know about all these options ?  And is there no specific zone for the signature ?  using a `hspace{26em}` does not seem best practice. Idealy the signature should be aligned with the receiver adress

Comment: I think page 193 of the https://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf (closing section) will be usefull.  It mention `sigindent`  and `sigindent` to position the signature

Comment: The `\hspace{26em}` is only a short version of all the `\qquad` and `\quad` in your `signature` variable. I did not thought about it, because you did not ask for the alignment of the `signature`.

Comment: If you want to align the signature and the addresse use the [answer by @Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483840/43317) to your follow-up question.