# The scrlttr2 signature position with KOMA-Script pseudolength sigindent?

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I'm trying to align the signature with the destination address in a french styled letter.
I could use the very good [lettre](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettre) class as mentioned in my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483216/setting-the-date-position-to-the-top-right-in-a-nf-lco-french-style-koma-scrlt/483332?noredirect=1#comment1223493_483332) but I need `scrlttr2` to reuse the org-mode koma export back-end.

I tried setting the position with the following commands:

Test 0

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigindent}{-\useplength{refhpos}+\useplength{toaddrhpos}}}
\makeatother
```

Test 1

```
\setkomavar{signature}{Chef Abraracoursix,\\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
```

Test 2

```
\setkomavar{signature}{\hspace{26em}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]
{example-image}}
```

Test 3

```
\setkomavar{signature}{\hspace{26em}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
    {Chef Abraracoursix,\hfill \\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
  \end{minipage}}
```

But the signature is stuck to the left.
Here is my full code and the result I'm looking for.

```
% Created 2019-04-08 lun. 11:20
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{showframe} % to show the page boundaries from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298246/signatures-side-by-side

% \usepackage{geometry} 
% \geometry{verbose,a4paper,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head,foot,address,location,refline}
\LoadLetterOption{NF}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\subjectname}{Objet}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\ccname}{C.c.}

\KOMAoption{
  ,foldmarks=false
  ,refline=nodate
  ,subject=titled
  ,fromemail=false
  ,fromlogo=false
  ,fromphone=false
  ,fromurl=false
  ,backaddress=false
  ,foldmarks=false
}


% from name
\setkomavar{fromname}{Chef Abraracoursix}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% signature

%%%% test 1
% \setkomavar{signature}{Chef Abraracoursix,\\Un chef à toujours bras long.}

%%%% test 2
% \setkomavar{signature}{\hspace{26em}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}}% <- changed

%%%% test 3
% \setkomavar{signature}{\hspace{26em}
%   \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
%     {Chef Abraracoursix,\hfill \\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
%   \end{minipage}}

%%%% test 4
\setkomavar{signature}{
  \noindent \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{Chef Abraracoursix,\hfill \\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% above %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% from adress
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Place du village,\\Erqy,\\Armorique}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}

% place and location
\setkomavar{place}{Erqy}
\setkomavar{placeseparator}{, le }

% other komavar
\setkomavar{ccseparator}{}
\setkomavar*{ccseparator}{\llap{\ccname\quad}}
% \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{lipsum} \setstretch{1.15}

% \setlength\parskip{\medskipamount} 
% \setlength\parindent{0pt}
% \setstretch{1.15}

\date{\today}

\makeatletter
% firsthead
\setkomavar{firsthead}{{
    \usekomafont{fromaddress}
    \parbox[b]{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{
      {\usekomafont{fromname}\usekomavar{fromname}}
      \hfill{\usekomafont{placeanddate}
        \ifkomavarempty{place}{}{\usekomavar{place}\usekomavar{placeseparator}}
        \usekomavar{date}
      }
      \\\usekomavar{fromaddress}
      \medskip
      \if@phone\\\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\fi
      \if@mobilephone\\\usekomavar*{frommobilephone}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\fi
      \if@fax\\\usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\fi
      \if@email\\\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\fi
      \if@www\\\usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}\fi
    }}
}

makeatletter
%%%% TEST 0
% \@setplength{sigindent}{-\useplength{refhpos}+\useplength{toaddrhpos}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}


\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Chef Abraracoursix},
  pdftitle={Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
  pdflang={French}}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti}

\begin{letter}{
    Capitaine Paulus Romanicus\\
    Camp de Babaorum
    Bretany}

  \opening{Le Romain,}

  Dans le cadre des rapports de bon voisinage et de notre hospitalité légendaire, nous vous invitons à festoyer avec nous sous le grand chêne, du coucher du soleil à l'aube, à la prochaine plein lune pour le mariage de la belle Fabala et de vigourix.
  \closing{À la tienne !}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting letter]

Idealy I would like

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigindent}{-\useplength{refhpos}+\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\makeatother
```

to work as expected with pseudo-lenght given in https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2tu3.png

Comment: Do not just look at the pseudo-length image from the documentation, but read the descriptions of the pseudo-lengths carefully. Some of them are set to special values by default, eg. 0pt. Then the class calculates the length of the positions of the letter elements when "opening". The rules for the calculations are described in the documentation. Especially the value of  `refhpos` is 0pt in your example and must not be used for the calculation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your calculation `-\useplength{refhpos}+\useplength{toaddhpos}` does not result in a value, that moves the signature to the middle of the text area.

In your example the value of `refhpos` is 0pt and the value of `toaddrhpos` is -10mm (given by `NF.lco`). Your

```
\@setplength{sigindent}{-\useplength{refhpos}+\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
```

(I've remove one `}`, which was to much), would result in a `sigindent` of -10mm. This would result in a position 10mm left to the left edge of the text area. So it is not what you want.

The image you've linked (which is [figure 22.1 of the current KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#figure.22.1)), is about address fields at the left side. You are using an address field on the right side. So `toaddrhpos` is the distance from the right paper edge to the right address field edge. It is negative (as told above). The `refhpos` has nothing to do with the position of the address field.

Please have a look into [table 22.1 in part II of the KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#table.22.1) and into the [descriptions of the pseudo length in section 22.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#section.22.1) to see, how the values of [`toaddhpos`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#desc:scrlttr2-experts.plength.toaddrhpos), [`refhpos`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#desc:scrlttr2-experts.plength.refhpos) and [`sigindent`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#desc:scrlttr2-experts.plength.sigindent) are interpreted by `scrlttr2`.

You may try something like:

```
\setplength{sigindent}{.5\textwidth}
```

Or a more complicate but correct calculation:

```
\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in}
```

Note: This does only work for `toaddrhpos` < 0.

`\paperwidth+\useplenth{toaddrhpos}` is the position of the right edge of the address field relative to the left edge of the paper. Subtracting `\useplength{toaddrwidth}` results in the left edge of the address field relative to the left edge of the paper. Adding `\useplength{toaddrindent}` results in the left edge of the address relative to the left edge of the paper. But `sigindent` is relative to the left edge of the text area not the paper. So we have to subtract the left margin, which is (in oneside documents for all pages) `\oddsidemargin+1in`.

Note: Since KOMA-Script 3.26 `\setplength` instead of `\@setplength` is recommended. `\@setplength` is an internal command now. You should not longer use it. If you are using an outdated KOMA-Script release you still have to use `\@setplength`. But in this case also expressions in the second argument would not be allowed. So you would have to use:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigindent}{\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax}
\makeatother
```

or split the calculation into several `\@addtoplength`.

Here is an example (using KOMA-Script >= 3.26), that illustrates the calculation:

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=11pt,
  french,
]{scrlttr2}[2018/12/22]% for KOMA-Script < v3.26 see the note about \setplengt` above

\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,xcolor}% for demonstration only

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{head,foot,address,location,refline}
\LoadLetterOption{NF}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\subjectname}{Objet}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\ccname}{C.c.}

\KOMAoptions{
  ,foldmarks=false
  ,refline=nodate
  ,subject=titled
  ,fromemail=false
  ,fromlogo=false
  ,fromphone=false
  ,fromurl=false
  ,backaddress=false
  ,foldmarks=false
}

% from name
\setkomavar{fromname}{Chef Abraracoursix}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}

\setkomavar{signature}{\noindent Chef Abraracoursix,\\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in}
% Show the calculation (for demonstration only)
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \footnotesize
    \put(0,-\useplength{toaddrvpos}){%
      \vector(1,0){\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}%
    }%
    \put(0,-\useplength{toaddrvpos}){%
      \makebox(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax,\ht\strutbox)[cb]{\ttfamily\detokenize{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}}}%
    }%
    \color{red!80!blue!80}%
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax,-\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+\ht\strutbox\relax){%
      \vector(-1,0){\useplength{toaddrwidth}}%
    }%
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}\relax,-\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+\ht\strutbox\relax){%

      \makebox(\useplength{toaddrwidth},\ht\strutbox)[cb]{\ttfamily\detokenize{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}}%
    }%
    \color{red!60!blue!60}%
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}\relax,-\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+\ht\strutbox*2\relax){%
      \vector(1,0){\useplength{toaddrindent}}%
    }%
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}\relax,-\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+\ht\strutbox*2\relax){%
      \makebox(\useplength{toaddrindent},\ht\strutbox){%
        \ttfamily\detokenize{\useplength{toaddrindent}}%
      }%
    }%
    \color{green}%
    \put(\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    -\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+2cm\relax){%
      \vector(1,0){%
        \dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax
      }%
    }%
    \put(\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    -\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrvpos}+2cm\relax){%
      \makebox(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax,\ht\strutbox)[lb]{%
        \detokenize{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}-\oddsidemargin-1in}%
      }%
    }%
    \color{blue}%
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}+\useplength{toaddrindent}\relax,0){%
      \line(0,-1){\paperheight}%
    }%
  }%
}

% from adress
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Place du village,\\Erqy,\\Armorique}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}

% place and location
\setkomavar{place}{Erqy}
\setkomavar{placeseparator}{, le }

% other komavar
\setkomavar{ccseparator}{}
\setkomavar*{ccseparator}{\llap{\ccname\quad}}

\date{\today}

% firsthead
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \usekomafont{fromaddress}%
    \parbox[b]{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
      {\usekomafont{fromname}\usekomavar{fromname}}%
      \hfill{%
        \usekomafont{placeanddate}%
        \ifkomavarempty{place}{}{\usekomavar{place}\usekomavar{placeseparator}}
        \usekomavar{date}
      }%
      \\\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
      \medskip
      \if@phone\\\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\fi%
      \if@mobilephone\\\usekomavar*{frommobilephone}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\fi%
      \if@fax\\\usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\fi%
      \if@email\\\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\fi%
      \if@www\\\usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}\fi%
    }%
}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\hypersetup{%
  pdfauthor={Chef Abraracoursix},
  pdftitle={Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
  pdflang={French}
}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti}

\begin{letter}{%
    Capitaine Paulus Romanicus\\
    Camp de Babaorum
    Bretany}

\opening{Le Romain,}

Dans le cadre des rapports de bon voisinage et de notre hospitalité 
légendaire, nous vous invitons à festoyer avec nous sous le grand chêne, 
du coucher du soleil à l'aube, à la prochaine plein lune pour le mariage 
de la belle Fabala et de vigourix.
\closing{À la tienne !}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, there were several other issues with your code:

> ```
> \usepackage[francais]{babel}
> ```

is deprecated. Current `babel` warns:

> ```
> Package francais.ldf Warning: Option `francais' for Babel is *deprecated*,
> (francais.ldf)                it might be removed sooner or later. Please
> (francais.ldf)                use `french' instead; reported on input line 31.
> ```

> ```
> \KOMAoption{
> ```

```
  ,foldmarks=false
  ,refline=nodate
  ,subject=titled
  ,fromemail=false
  ,fromlogo=false
  ,fromphone=false
  ,fromurl=false
  ,backaddress=false
  ,foldmarks=false
}
```

is wrong. `\KOMAoption` has two arguments. The first one is an option key, the second is a list of option values.

To help users to find out what's wrong, the current prerelease of KOMA-Script shows the following error message with your wrong usage of `\KOMAoption`:

> ```
> ./test.tex:28: Package scrbase Error: syntax error in key ` ,foldmarks=false ,r
> efline=nodate ,subject=titled ,fromemail=false ,fromlogo=false ,fromphone=false
>  ,fromurl=false ,backaddress=false ,foldmarks=false '.
>
> See the scrbase package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.28 }
>       
> You've used `\...Option' to set the key ` ,foldmarks=false ,refline=nodate ,sub
> ject=titled ,fromemail=false ,fromlogo=false ,fromphone=false ,fromurl=false ,b
> ackaddress=false ,foldmarks=false '
> to new value(s), but `,' is not allowed in the key of an option
> (and `\...Option' does not use `,' to separate several keys).
> Maybe you've meant \...Options instead of \...Option.
> If you'll continue, I'll give it a try, but you should expect further
> and even strange error messages.
> ```

As the help text of the error message explains:

```
\KOMAoptions{
  ,foldmarks=false
  ,refline=nodate
  ,subject=titled
  ,fromemail=false
  ,fromlogo=false
  ,fromphone=false
  ,fromurl=false
  ,backaddress=false
  ,foldmarks=false
}
```

would be correct.

Your definition of `firsthead` adds several significant but unwanted white spaces. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/9057) for more information how to avoid them.

There is also a warning message about usage of `\date`:

> ```
> Class scrlttr2 Warning: \date changes the internal \LaTeX date only.
> (scrlttr2)              You should note that this changes the default
> (scrlttr2)              value of variable `date' only as long as someone
> (scrlttr2)              uses `\setkomavar` to change the content of
> (scrlttr2)              variable `date'.
> (scrlttr2)              Therefore, usage of `\setkomavar' is recommended
> (scrlttr2)              to change the letter's date on input line 59.
> ```

So for `scrlttr2` you should use

```
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
```

or just remove it, because `\today` is already the default.

Last but not least, you have a

> ```
> makeatletter
> ```

instead of

```
\makeatletter
```

in your document preamble.

Comment: I provided the link to the pseudo-lengths https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2tu3.png for a letter where what I want is clearly - refhpos + toaddhpos.  What I don't understand is why all the above command have not impact on my signature's position.

Comment: As I told you: Your calculation `refhpos` + `toaddhpos` results in -10mm which is wrong. Try the two suggestions I made. The second one should be exactly what you are searching for. BTW: The picture is from the KOMA-Script manual. I know that picture.

Comment: I may have a latex version problem because I don't see any change and I'm not able to compile your code even on overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/7967172393zkcnhzmqsgcc at least if I could move the signature by an inch, I'm sure I would find the right calculation to place it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for all your corrections.  It is helpful.

Comment: @MalikKoné The code is tested with TeX Live 2018 and the current official KOMA-Script v3.26b. It is also tested with TeX Live 2019 pretest and KOMA-Script v3.27.3111 prerelease.

Comment: @MalikKoné Overleaf uses AFAIK an older TeX Live 2017 with a historic KOMA-Script version. So you still have to use `\makeatletter\@setplength…\makeatother` there. Moreover it does not provide calculation in the second argument of `\@setplength`. So you have to either use explicit `\dimexpr` or split it into several `\@addtoplength`.

Comment: Ok, got it working after installing recent TeX Live version.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is the same as in the [answer of @Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483840/43317). But it is too long for a comment ... maybe the following helps to understand why `refhpos` is completely wrong in the calculation of the desired indent of the signature, ie the pseudolength `sigindent`.

First of all: Do not just look at the pseudolength-image in the documentation, but read the descriptions of all pseudolengths carefully. By default some of them are set to special values, eg. `0pt`. Then the positions of these letter elements are calculated and used in a group during the excecution of `\opening`. The rules for these calculations are described in the documentation.

Note that pseudolength `refhpos` is **not** the distance between the left edge of the paper and the letter body! It only determines the horizontal position of the reference line **if** the pseudolengths `refwidth` is not zero. But `refwidth` is typically set to `0pt`, eg in the NF.lco. With this special value the lengths *and* the position of the reference line depend only on option `refline` and its values `narrow` (default) or `wide`.

Examples:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}\showfields{address,location,refline}% visualize position of addresse and refline

%\KOMAoptions{refline=wide}% uncomment for the 2.image, default is refline=narrow

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{recipient\\address}
\opening{Hello}
Pseudolength \texttt{refwidth} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{refwidth}},
pseudolength \texttt{refhpos} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{refhpos}} and
pseudolength \texttt{sigindent} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{sigindent}}.
\par\bigskip
\blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result with default `refline` settings (`refline=narrow`):

[image]

Result with `refline=wide` (uncomment the line in the code above):

[image]

If you set `refhpos` to a different value, the layout will not change:

```
\setplength{refhpos}{10pt}
```

Result with default `refline=narrow` (see the first example):

[image]

Note that only the value in the text has changed.

But if you set pseudolength `refwidth` to a nonzero value, e.g.

```
  \setplength{refwidth}{\textwidth}
```

you get

[image]

or with

```
\setplength{refhpos}{10pt}
\setplength{refwidth}{\textwidth}
```

[image]

Note that this behavior is described in the KOMA-Script documentation.

---

To align the signature with the addresse, we have to add the pseudolengths `toaddrhpos` and `toaddrindent` and to subtract the left margin (=`\oddsidemargin+1pt`):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}\showfields{address,location,refline}% visualize position of addresse and refline

\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}% % signature should be raggedright as in NF.lco
\setkomavar{signature}{\color{red}\smash{\rule[-\paperheight]{.4pt}{2\paperheight}}}% to show the left margin of the signature

%\setplength{toaddrhpos}{100pt}
\setplength{sigindent}{
  \useplength{toaddrhpos}+\useplength{toaddrindent}
  -\oddsidemargin-1in% remove left margin
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{recipient\\address}
\opening{Hello}
Pseudolength \texttt{refhpos} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{refhpos}},
pseudolength \texttt{toaddrhpos} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{toaddrhpos}},
pseudolength \texttt{toaddrindent} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{toaddrindent}} and
pseudolength \texttt{sigindent} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{sigindent}}.
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

and if you set `toaddrhpos` to 100pt (uncomment the line in the code above):

[image]

If you set `toaddrhpos` to the width of the left margin

```
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{\oddsidemargin+1in}
```

you get

[image]

---

Loading NF.lco the value of `toaddrhpos` get negative. A negative value means that`toaddrhpos` is the distance from the right edge of the address field
to the right edge of the paper. Therefore we have to add `\paperwidth` and subtract the width of the address field (`toaddrwidth`):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}\showfields{address,location,refline}% visualize position of addresse and refline
\setkomavar{signature}{\color{red}\smash{\rule[-\paperheight]{.4pt}{2\paperheight}}}% to show the left margin of the signature

\LoadLetterOption{NF}

\setplength{sigindent}{
  \useplength{toaddrhpos}+\useplength{toaddrindent}
  -\oddsidemargin-1in
}
\ifdim\useplength{toaddrhpos}<0pt
  \addtoplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth-\useplength{toaddrwidth}}
\fi


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{recipient\\address}
\opening{Hello}
Pseudolength \texttt{refhpos} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{refhpos}},
pseudolength \texttt{toaddrhpos} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{toaddrhpos}},
pseudolength \texttt{toaddrindent} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{toaddrindent}} and
pseudolength \texttt{sigindent} is set to \textbf{\the\useplength{sigindent}}.
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

See also the image in the [answer of @Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483840/43317).

You can change `toaddrhpos` before the calculation of `sigindent`, eg

```
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{-100pt}
```

Result:

[image]

---

So I would suggest the same as [@Schweineback in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483840/43317):

With an uptodate KOMA-Script Version (at least 3.26):

```
\setplength{sigindent}{
  \useplength{toaddrhpos}+\useplength{toaddrindent}
  -\oddsidemargin-1in
  }
\ifdim\useplength{toaddrhpos}<0pt
  \addtoplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth-\useplength{toaddrwidth}}
\fi
```

or with older versions:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigindent}{\dimexpr
  \useplength{toaddrhpos}+\useplength{toaddrindent}
  -\oddsidemargin-1in
  \relax}
\ifdim\useplength{toaddrhpos}<0pt
  \@addtoplength{sigindent}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\useplength{toaddrwidth}\relax}
\fi
\makeatother
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that pseudolength `toaddrhpos` is set in `NF.lco` to a negative value of `-10mm` with command `\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{-10mm}`.

That means that the value of `10mm` is not the value between left paper side and address field, it is the value between the **right paper side** and the adress box. Usually the adress box is printed first (on the left side of the paper) and the location box follows then. With file `NF-lco` that changed as you already showed in your picture in your question.

`sigindent` is always calculated from the left side of the typing area, so you have to calculate the needed value for `sigindent` by yourself.

One possibility is:

```
\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{refhpos}}
```

That means we calculate the `\paperwidth` minus `toaddrhpos` (because its value is already minus we have to use plus here) minus `toaddrwidth` minus `refhpos` minus two times `toaddrindent`.

With that calculation in your corrected given code

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=11pt,
  french,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{head,foot,address,location,refline}
\LoadLetterOption{NF}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\subjectname}{Objet}
\renewcaptionname{french}{\ccname}{C.c.}

\KOMAoptions{
  ,foldmarks=false
  ,refline=nodate
  ,subject=titled
  ,fromemail=false
  ,fromlogo=false
  ,fromphone=false
  ,fromurl=false
  ,backaddress=false
  ,foldmarks=false
}

% from name
\setkomavar{fromname}{Chef Abraracoursix}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}

\setkomavar{signature}{\noindent Chef Abraracoursix,\\Un chef à toujours bras long.}
\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{refhpos}} % <===============

% from adress
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Place du village,\\Erqy,\\Armorique}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}

% place and location
\setkomavar{place}{Erqy}
\setkomavar{placeseparator}{, le }

% other komavar
\setkomavar{ccseparator}{}
\setkomavar*{ccseparator}{\llap{\ccname\quad}}

\date{\today}


% firsthead
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \usekomafont{fromaddress}%
    \parbox[b]{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
      {\usekomafont{fromname}\usekomavar{fromname}}%
      \hfill{%
        \usekomafont{placeanddate}%
        \ifkomavarempty{place}{}{\usekomavar{place}\usekomavar{placeseparator}}
        \usekomavar{date}
      }%
      \\\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
      \medskip
      \if@phone\\\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\fi%
      \if@mobilephone\\\usekomavar*{frommobilephone}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\fi%
      \if@fax\\\usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\fi%
      \if@email\\\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\fi%
      \if@www\\\usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}\fi%
    }%
}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\hypersetup{%
  pdfauthor={Chef Abraracoursix},
  pdftitle={Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
  pdflang={French}
}


\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{Invitation pour une banquet au sanglier Roti}

\begin{letter}{%
    Capitaine Paulus Romanicus\\
    Camp de Babaorum
    Bretany}

\opening{Le Romain,}

Dans le cadre des rapports de bon voisinage et de notre hospitalité 
légendaire, nous vous invitons à festoyer avec nous sous le grand chêne, 
du coucher du soleil à l'aube, à la prochaine plein lune pour le mariage 
de la belle Fabala et de vigourix.
\closing{À la tienne !}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: result]

It seems there is a difference of `5pt` too much I do not know where it comes from (rounding errors, an indent I did not saw?). In the case of this mwe you can add them to the calculation with:

```
\setplength{sigindent}{\paperwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}-\useplength{toaddrwidth}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{toaddrindent}-\useplength{refhpos}-5pt}
```

Comment: I have removed some comments here which focus on technical aspects of the answer but which had become discursive. To summarise briefly, this answer is based on public details of the data/calculation steps in KOMA, but the KOMA author and others suggest that this does not give the correct results: see https://komascript.de/comment/6060#comment-6060. This may well be due to deficiencies in the documentation.